# Confusion about the total mean curvature of spheres in a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I am browsing through [a paper](http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~pacard/Publications/54.pdf) and I am confused by a notation the meaning of which I do not understand.

Let $S_{p,\rho}$ be the geodesic sphere of center $p$ and radius $\rho$ in a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ of $\dim \ M = m+1$ (with $\rho$ less than the injectivity radius at $p$). Let $S^m$ be the unit sphere in $T_p M$; note that there exist the global parametrization $S^m \to S_{p,\rho}$ given by $\Theta \mapsto \exp _p (\rho \Theta)$.

If $H(S_{p,\rho})$ is the total mean curvature of $S_{p,\rho}$ (which I suspect to be the integral over $S_{p,\rho}$ of the mean curvature at every point, but I am not sure), then the first formula on page 2 of the paper claims that

$$H(S_{p,\rho}) = \frac m \rho - \frac 1 3 Ric_p (\Theta, \Theta) \rho + O(\rho ^2) .$$

What I do not understand here is why the coefficient of $\rho$ depends on a point $\Theta \in S^m$ (which one?) when the left-hand side should be independent of it. Shouldn't there maybe be some integration on $S^m$ to take care of that $\Theta$? What am I not understanding?

Comment: $H(S_{\rho,\rho})$ is the mean curvature at the point $\exp_p (\rho \Theta)$, not the total  mean curvature.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: In fact, I am interested in the coefficient of $\frac {\partial} {\partial r}$ from the formula of the Laplacian in spherical geodesic coordinates. In [Bennett Chow's book](https://books.google.ro/books?id=p3j0BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA400) it is $H(w,p)$, the mean curvature of $S_{p,\rho}$ at he point $w \in S_{p,\rho}$. In [Gerard Meurant"s book](https://books.google.ro/books?id=exqJ3RtPMYYC&pg=PA313) it is $\frac {A'(\rho)} {A(\rho)}$, with $A(\rho)$ the area of $S_{p,\rho}$ (which depends only on $\rho$). I am totally confused, can you please enlighten me?

Comment: In a homogeneous space (so that geodesic spheres have constant mean curvature) those two expressions are equal. In general $A'(\rho) = \int H d A$ - this is the first variation of area formula.